# file is running a different main

Tags: java, netbeans, package

I'm creating a ChatApp with Netbeans. I used the systems "New Project" and have a Server.java file and Client.java file. I attached a screenshot of the file structure.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmtld.jpg)

My problem is that after I start the Server.java, I start the Client.java file and it runs the Server.java file again. It ignores the code I have in Client.java.

What am I doing wrong.

My code:

```
public class ChatAppServer extends JFrame{
     private int portNumber;
     public static int flag = 0;

     public ChatAppServer(){
         askPortNum();
         createServer();
     }

     void askPortNum(){
    // use flag to check if this was already asked
    if(flag == 0){
        try{
            // save input to variable
            portNumber = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
                    "Enter a port number", "Port Number", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));
            // change flag to 1
            flag = 1;                
            // call buildGUI
            buildGUI();
        }catch(NumberFormatException numFor){
            // set variable number value
            portNumber = 9999;
            // pop message letting the user know
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Number expected. Using port " + portNumber, "Invalid Entry", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            buildGUI();
        }catch(Exception e){
            portNumber = 9999;
            // pop message letting the user know
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not valid port number. Using port " + portNumber, "Invalid Entry", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            buildGUI();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ChatAppServer();
    }
}
```

This is my Client code:

```
import static chatappAll.ChatAppServer.flag;

public class ChatAppClient extends JFrame{
     // message section
private JScrollPane dmScrollPane;
private JTextArea messageArea;

// user section
private JScrollPane utScrollPane;
private JTextArea userTextArea;

public ChatAppClient(){
    askPortNum();
}

void askPortNum(){
    if(flag == 1){
        System.out.println("looks good");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new ChatAppClient();
}
```

}

Comment: What does your build configuration look like? You should be able to select a targeted Class there.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with your actual code, but with how your IDE (in this case, NetBeans) starts the programs.

Comment: Just right click the class you want in the file structure and click run.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I was able to get it to run by right-clicking the file. This brings up another question: when I create the JAR file, will it handle this for me?